# SSRS 2008 Add value to parameter resultset

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

We implemented a new system. Read-only access to the database. Writing reports for current and historical data. Using drill through report to display location and number of people there. Select the count of the location and go to details.

I query the location table to populate a parameters values. This works properly.

What I want is to ADD "Pre-Implementation" to the Parameters result set to cover the NULLS that exist because the data was before the implementation date. The phrase needs to appear in the drop-down list of locations so the user can select it. The phrase listed above needs to appears on the report.  How would you do this?

What I have tried:
Have query that returns "Pre-Implementation" along with active locations for the time period.  SSRS will not display as a choice in a drill through report.

Comment: Have you tried changing the date field to a text field and then using an expression to check if the returned value is null and then display "Pre-Implementation" if it is?

Comment: Yes in the SQL I have, I detect the NULL and substitute the phrase.  However SSRS will not recognize the new value.

Comment: If you're wanting to do it in SQL you'll have to make sure the field you're returning is a varchar. If it is still a datetime then it won't return "Pre-Implementation" as that's a different datatype. To do this you'll need to Cast / convert your date in sql to a varchar

Comment: Thanks.  The SQL is working but when I put the working SQL into a data set in the report, I get the locations  but not the "Pre-Implementation" displaying in the report.

Comment: Have you set the field on the table to a text field? If you don't specify it is that then SSRS will assume it is a date field.

Comment: Yes the date field has been cast:  (CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(@StartDate AS CHAR(12)), 101))) but I'm struggling with the location field.  In SQL it works. in SSRS the "extra value" is not detected.

Comment: ,f.location
,(CASE 
 WHEN f.location IS NULL
 THEN 'PRE-Implementation'
 ELSE f.location
  END
 ) as newcolumn
,cd.full_name

Comment: What type is f.location? is it a varchar?

Comment: Yes its a varchar(30)

Comment: Can you try this: CASE WHEN f.location = '' THEN 'PRE-Implementation' ELSE f.location END. I suspect as it's a varchar it will be passing in an empty string rather than a null. PS - thats two separate apostrophes